# 'Create Records' option missing in the Add element in Lightning Flows

Tags: lightning-flow-builder, flow-builder

I am new to Lightning Flows.
I am currently using a Record-Triggered flow to update a field in Opportunity and I want to insert exception records using the custom Exception Object.
I have populated the object record using Assignment, but I am not able to see the 'Create Records' add element. Only 'Update Records' and a couple of other options.

Let me know if you know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have missed selecting "Actions and related records" option as shown below.

[image]

You can still use your flow, go to Start element and edit, you will see the above screen, now update your options, and you will see all the actions.

What you selected is meant for before trigger changes, things like, updating the context records.

Comment: Yep, it was the issue. I was able to edit the flow and update the optimization to 'Actions and Related Records'. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think, it is a bug, you can save and close the flow, logout from your org.

Then login back and open the flow, the "Create Record" element should be there.

OR

Just create a new record-trigger flow.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: It was not a bug. I had to choose a different type of optimization for the flow, in the flow settings. Thanks :)